# Splay Tree implementation: Search function - Zag zag rotation wrong

Tags: javascript, algorithm, data-structures

I am testing Zag-zag rotation with a right-skewed tree. Before that, I had tested Zig-zig, Zig-zag rotation with a left-skewed tree and OK.

Here is my code:

```js
// An AVL tree node
class Node {
  constructor(key) {
    this.key = key;
    this.left = this.right = null;
  }
}

function rightRotate(root) {
  const rootLeft = root.left; // saving the reference

  root.left = rootLeft.right;
  rootLeft.right = root;

  return rootLeft; // new root
}

function leftRotate(root) {
  const rootRight = root.right;

  root.right = rootRight.left;
  rootRight.left = root;

  return rootRight;
}

// This function modifies the tree and returns the new root
// - If has key, Brings the key at root
// - Else, brings the last accessed item at root.
function splay(root, key) {
  // Base cases
  if (root === null || root.key === key) return root; // bring last accessed element or founded element as root of left-left (sub)tree

  // Grandparent start here
  // Key lies in Left
  if (key < root.key) {
    // Key is not in tree
    if (root.left === null) return root; // If not founded, Bring last accessed element root of left (sub)tree

    // Parent start here
    // Zig-Zig (Left Left)
    if (key < root.left.key) {
      root.left.left = splay(root.left.left, key);

      // Do first rotation for root, brind child as parent of subtree
      root = rightRotate(root);
    }
    // Zig-Zag (Left Right)
    else if (key > root.left.key) {
      root.left.right = splay(root.left.right, key);

      // Do first rotation for root.left, brind child as parent of subtree
      if (root.left.right != null) root.left = leftRotate(root.left);
    }

    // 1 cong 2 viec
    // 1. Do second rotation, bring child as grandparent of subtree
    // 2. Bring parent (level 2) as root of tree when last recursive splay() finish
    return rightRotate(root);
    // Parent end
  }
  // Key lies in Right
  else {
    if (root.right === null) return root;

    // Parent start here
    // Zag-Zag (Right Right)
    if (key > root.right.key) {
      root.right.right = splay(root.right.right, key);

      root = leftRotate(root);
    }
    // Zag-Zig (Right Left)
    else if (key < root.right.key) {
      root.right.left = splay(root.right.left, key);

      if (root.right.left != null) root.right = rightRotate(root.right);
    }

    return leftRotate(root);
    // End parent
  }
  // Grandparent end
}

// The search function for Splay tree.
// This function returns the new root of Splay Tree.
// If key is present in tree then, it is moved to root.
// else, last accessed element is moved to root
function search(root, key) {
  return splay(root, key);
}

// A utility function to print
// preorder traversal of the tree.
// The function also prints height of every node
function preOrder(root) {
  if (root != null) {
    console.log(root.key);
    preOrder(root.left);
    preOrder(root.right);
  }
}

// Right-skewed tree for Zag-zag and Zag-zig test
// Using root2 to console.log in other function like splay, search (because they have argument name "root")
let root2 = new Node(10);
root2.right = new Node(15);
root2.right.right = new Node(16);
root2.right.right.right = new Node(20);
root2.right.right.right.right = new Node(21);
root2.right.right.right.right.right = new Node(22);
root2 = splay(root2, 20);
console.log(root2)
```

Assume we search for node 20. The rotation should happen as follow:

1. Zag-zag rotation: Replace node 15 with 20.

[image: op1]

[image: op2]

2. Zag rotation: Replace node 10 with 20

[image: op3]

[image: op4]

However, my code result is:

[image: op5]

*Demo of image used [this](https://www.cs.usfca.edu/%7Egalles/visualization/SplayTree.html)*

Comment: @trincot Wait what. Open the console!!! I don't clone nodes, I change its reference

Comment: @trincot My fault, forgot to save after edit.

Comment: OK, I inserted your code as a snippet into your question.

Comment: @trincot Is that too long to be readed for a post?

Comment: No, the snippet is boxed. But it is needed as information to understand what the question is about (your code essentially). Readers should be able to reproduce what you describe as the problem.

Comment: Still, I see that the pictures are about a different scenario than in the code. Could you align them? In the code you have the left-skewed case, but your question is about the right-skewed case. Your could should show the *problem*, so it should run the right-skewed case. And it should search 20, like in the images.

Comment: @trincot I ask the question on codereview exchange and they require me put the non-bug version, so I comment out the code of right-skewed tree, which lie below the left-skewed tree code you paste in the snippet. I just edit that.

Comment: The rules on code review are different. There you must post working code, asking for review (best practices, efficiency, ...etc). There you cannot ask for *fixing* a problem. Here you can not ask for *review*, but about a problem, and you should provide the code with which the problem can be reproduced.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both your algorithm and the imaged algorithm perform double rotations correctly, every time taking a pair of edges on the path to the target node, and applying a double rotation on that pair.

However, when the path to the target node has an *odd* length, then there is one edge that will undergo a *single* rotation. The choice of this single edge is different:

- your algorithm will "split" the path in pairs starting from the root node, treating the remaining single edge at the *end* of the path separately.
- the imaged algorithm will "split" the path in pairs starting from the target node, treating the remaining single edge at the *start* of the path (at the root) separately.

Here is your code aligned with that second strategy:

```
function splay(root, key) {
    function splaySub(root) {
        if (!root) throw new RangeError; // Value not found in tree
        if (root.key === key) return root;
        let side = key < root.key ? "left" : "right";
        root[side] = splaySub(root[side]);
        // Check if odd: then caller to deal with rotation
        if (root[side].key === key) return root; 
        // Apply a double rotation, top-down:
        root = key < root.key ? rightRotate(root) : leftRotate(root);
        return key < root.key ? rightRotate(root) : leftRotate(root);
    }

    try {
        root = splaySub(root);
        return !root || root.key === key 
           // Path had even length: all OK
           ? root
           // Odd length: Perform a final, single rotation
           : key < root.key ? rightRotate(root) : leftRotate(root);
    } catch(e) {
        if (!(e instanceof RangeError)) throw e;
        return root; // Not found: return original tree
    }
}
```

When the searched value is not in the tree, this code will trigger an Exception, so to exit quickly out of recursion without any update to the tree. In this case that approach makes the code a bit cleaner (fewer checks for `null` values...).

#### Addendum

As in comments you explained that the `splay` function should also bring a node to the top when it doesn't find the value, I provide here the updated code. I took the opportunity to turn the code into more OOP style, so you'll find here some of your functions turned into methods:

```js
class Node {
    constructor(key, left=null, right=null) {
        this.key = key;
        this.left = left;
        this.right = right;
    }
    * inOrder(depth=0) {
        if (this.right) yield * this.right.inOrder(depth+1);
        yield [depth, this.key];
        if (this.left) yield * this.left.inOrder(depth+1);
    }
    _rotate(toRight) {
        const [side, otherSide] = toRight ? ["right", "left"] : ["left", "right"];
        const orig = this[otherSide];
        this[otherSide] = orig[side];
        orig[side] = this;
        return orig;
    }
    rightRotate() {
        return this._rotate(true);
    }
    leftRotate() {
        return this._rotate(false);
    }
    insert(key) {
        const side = key < this.key ? "left" : "right";
        if (this[side]) return this[side].insert(key);
        this[side] = new Node(key);
    }
}

class SplayTree {
    constructor(...values) {
        this.root = null;
        for (const value of values) this.insert(value);
    }
    insert(value) {
        if (this.root) this.root.insert(value);
        else this.root = new Node(value);
    }
    splay(key) {
        if (!this.root) return;
        
        function splaySub(root) {
            if (root.key === key) return root;
            const side = key < root.key ? "left" : "right";
            // Not found? Then do as if we looked for current node's key
            if (!root[side]) {
                key = root.key; // Modifies the outer-scoped variable
                return root; 
            }
            root[side] = splaySub(root[side]);
            // Check if odd: then caller to deal with rotation
            if (root[side].key === key) return root; 
            // Apply a double rotation, top-down:
            root =  root._rotate(key < root.key);
            return  root._rotate(key < root.key);
        }

        this.root = splaySub(this.root);
        if (this.root.key !== key) this.root = this.root._rotate(key < this.root.key);
    }
    search(key) {
        this.splay(key);
    }
    * inOrder() {
        if (this.root) yield * this.root.inOrder();
    }
    toString() {
        return Array.from(tree.inOrder(), ([depth, key]) => "  ".repeat(depth) + key).join("\n");
    }
}

const tree = new SplayTree(10, 15, 16, 20, 21, 22);
console.log("Initial tree:");
console.log(tree.toString());
tree.search(19); // Not found, so it splays 20.
console.log("Final tree:");
console.log(tree.toString());
```

Comment: Actually, when the searched value is not in the tree, I need to bring the last accessed element to the root (treat it as the founded node and do the rotations). Though, your double rotation code had decoupled my twisted code; the combined "side" variable is beautiful. Thanks for the improvement.

Comment: Ok, so do you have a problem in bringing that node to the top? If so, then that sounds like a different question.

Comment: I will try handle that. Some question: 1. The line you comment`// Check if odd: then caller to deal with rotation`, what you mean is if the return path is even length? (example: splay(20) -> Founded 20, return to 16 -> 16->20 is odd length -> continue return -> 15->16->20 is not odd = Rotation); 2. The code you deal with odd length `return (!root || root.key === key) ? root : ...`, why return root if there is "no root"?

Comment: (1) Yes, I meant 16->20 is odd, so no (single) rotation is done to bring 20 up, but instead the caller (who sees 15->16->20) should do the double rotation.  (2) this is just a shortcut to not have to write a separate `if (!root) return null`.

Comment: I extended my answer. Have a look.